# Saving image from html to canvas

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which works in firefox but not in chrome and ie.

What I want to achieve is that on click the #btnSave input the #widget div gets created into a canvas and then asks the user to save it as an image on their computer.

```
$(function() {
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

             //save image
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, "image.png");
            });

            // Clean up 
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use this polyfill to make it work in the browsers that don't support it out of the box: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

Documentation on [canvas.toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob):

> The HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob() method creates a Blob object
>   representing the image contained in the canvas; this file may be
>   cached on the disk or stored in memory at the discretion of the user
>   agent. If type is not specified, the image type is image/png. The
>   created image is in a resolution of 96dpi.